# Streamlit cannot import sklearn module

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, streamlit

I'm just trying to learn a bit about data science here and following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8M20LyCZDOY

However, when I run the program, it says that sklearn isn't installed even though I installed it through pip3 and pip with the code on my terminal:

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

Here was the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

Traceback:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 554, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)

File "/Users/jeettan/Desktop/python-programming/programming.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sklearn import datasets
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to make sure that the module is installed on the correct environment. Are you using the native Python interpreter or through a virtual environment? Try running 'python -c "import sklearn" ' in your terminal and see if that throws an error. If it doesn't, it means that you are trying to run your program with a different version from the one sklearn is installed on.

Comment: There was no error when I ran the program. How do I match the version up?

Comment: Hello, found the answer - just posted it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
sudo pip3 install scikit-learn
```

I tried with `pip3 install scikit-learn` but it did not work, but adding `sudo` before did the trick.